# log4net add date to rolled logs only

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a log file cofigured using log4net. I've managed to get the log rolling working wit appending a date however whene the date rolls my archived file is named

RogueLike.log_2023-02-10.log

What I am wanting is to have the archived file become

RogueLike_2023-02-10.log

This is my log4net  appender settings.

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="'_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'"/>
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="D:\Projects\Logs\RogueLike\RogueLike.Log" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5level %-60c %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Log files are “rolled” by appending something to the existing file name; in this case the date with a particular format. There is no accommodation for modifying the file’s name first.

Comment: Ok, understood. So what I have is as good as I am going to get?

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible to do through configuration. Log4net is extensible and open source as well, so if it’s really important to remove the extension, you could probably find a way, though.